# Pandas get N row from each group after applying GroupBy on multiple column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have below data frame on which I have apply `GroupBy` on multiple columns which is working fine but I want only `two rows` from each group it creates after applying `GroupBy`.

```
ID    StudentName  Grade  City  School
12      AAA        B      NG     XX
15       BBB        C      HK     XY
18       CCC        A      NG     XX
09       DDD        A      HK     XY
01       EEE        C      NG     XX
22       FFF        B      HK     XY
```

When I have apply GroupBy to get the count of students I wrote below query which works fine for me

```
FinalData = DF.groupby(['City','School'])['ID'].count().reset_index(name='Count Of student')
```

But I want any 2 rows from each group after applying GroupBY as below:

```
          ID   StudentName    Grade   City   School 
Group1    12      AAA          B       NG      XX
Group2    09      DDD          A       HK      XY
```

Comment: `df.groupby().head(2)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, I have tried that but it's giving all rows in output.

Comment: @QuangHoang, I guess it works only for single column GroupBy

Comment: pretty sure `df.groupby(['City','School']).head(2)` will give you 2 results from each group.